# React Native how to get a variable out of an async function and return it

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native

I dont know how to get the variable allP out of this function so i can return it to display on screen.

Ive tried defining the variable outside the function so i could call it in the code but that didnt work. the array prints out in the console log but i just cant seem to get it to show in the return.

```
sched = async () => {
var i = null;
var getPrice = null;
var allP =[];
try {
  const schedinfo = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(netidget));
  this.setState({ schedinfo: schedinfo.data.listLoginModals.items });
  for (i = 0; i < schedinfo.data.listLoginModals.items.length; i++) { 
  getPrice = schedinfo.data.listLoginModals.items[i].Type;  
   var lowP = await API.graphql( 
    graphqlOperation(lowest, {
      CIndex: getPrice   
    })
    )  
    if(typeof lowP.data.listlowestprice.items[0] == "undefined") {     
      lowP = "-";    
    } else {
      lowP = lowP.data.listlowestprice.items[0].Price.toString(); 
    }  
    if(lowP == " ") { 
        lowP = "-"; 
      }          
  allP.push(lowP);     
  }
  console.log(allP);  
  {this.state.lowprices.map(da => ( 
          <View item={da} key={da.id}>
          <Text>{da.Price}</Text>
          console.log(da.Price) 
          </View>
                    ))}

  console.log(schedinfo.data.listLoginModals.items.length)
 } catch (err) {
  console.log('error creating restaurant...', err);
 }
};
```

I want to be able to display the allP array that gets created from the function.  Please any help is appreciated thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code inside of your `try` sentence to a new async fuction, return it and receive that value on your `allP` variable (without arrow functions), so:

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.getAllP = this.getAllP.bind(this);
   this.sched = this.sched.bind(this);
}

async getAllP() {
   try {
   ....
   operations
   ....
   return allP
   }
}

async sched() {
   var allP = await getAllP();
}
```